# В PHPMyAdmin запрос обрабатывается, а в PHP нет, почему?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, sql

```
$sql = "select place_id, name, address, longitude, latitude  from place where latitude !=0 and latitude is not null";
$result = mysql_query($sql) || die (mysql_error());
$cnt = mysql_num_rows ($result);
```

На строчке  `$cnt = mysql_num_rows ($result);` выдает ошибку:

> `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in Z:\home\localhost\www\fsq\for_id.php on line 19`

В `PhpMyAdmin` запрос выполняла, работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, запрос у вас отлично выполняется. Просто поставьте `or` вместо `||`. У вас в `$result` записывается (судя по предупреждению) значение `true`.

Comment: слушайте, действительно тру записывался. спасибо. все работает. 
а я сижу тут уже все кругом перебираю

Comment: Все эти тексты ошибок часто как-то мутно записываются) грубо говоря, текст ошибки есть "первый аргумент `mysql_num_rows()` должен быть типа resource, а пришло boolean", т.е. `$result` оказалось равным либо `true`, либо `false`.